# Maximum Gain For Chopper Stabilized Instrumentation Amp (MCP6N11)

Tags: gain, instrumentation-amplifier, gain-bandwidth-product

I am using a Microchip [MCP6N11](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/en555897) chopper stabilized instrumentation amplifier to amplify the signal from a [MPX2300DT1](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/nxp-usa-inc/MPX2300DT1/MPX2300DT1CT-ND/3524227) Wheatstone bridge pressure sensor.  My schematic is attached.  As shown the gain is 170.  To get enough signal I need to increase it to at least 800.

According to the datasheet this may require too high a value of feedback resistor. In the datasheet there is a formula for the maximum feedback resistor:

[image: Gain]

I'm not sure what values to use for fGBWP and CG.

Can I safely get a gain of 800 to 1000 out of this type of instrumentation amplifier or should I add a second stage of amplification?  Frequency response only needs to go up to about 10,000 Hz.

This is my schematic:

[image: schematic]